# Processing fragment shader not displaying anything

Tags: glsl, processing

I seem to be having an issue getting a shader to work in Processing. I am working on an ink effect, and after getting some help to write the rest of the shader, I can't seem to get anything to happen. The color stays black, and when I change gl_FragColor = vertColor; (which Processing reserves for color), the image becomes white. From what I understand, it should just pass straight through in that case, so now I believe something might be wrong. Does anyone have some advice?

EDIT: I've made some changes to try to match it closer to what I see in other processing shaders. Instead of vertColor I am now using sampler2D(source,coord).rgb, which is still not working.

```
PShader shader;
PImage photo;

void setup() {
  size(619,619,P2D);
  photo = loadImage("paintedsky.jpg");
  shader = loadShader("inkspread.glsl");
}

void draw() {
  shader.set("T",(float) millis()/1000.0);
  shader(shader);
  image(photo,619,619);
}
```

---

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#endif

#define PROCESSING_TEXTURE_SHADER

uniform sampler2D source;
varying vec4 vertTexCoord;

uniform float T;
const float diag = 1.414213562373095;

vec3 F(vec3 x0,vec3 x1,float dist){
    return (x1 - x0)/(T * dist);
}

void main() {
    vec2 ix  = vertTexCoord.st;

    vec2 c11 = vertTexCoord.st + vec2( 0.0, 0.0);
    vec2 c01 = vertTexCoord.st + vec2(-1.0, 0.0);
    vec2 c21 = vertTexCoord.st + vec2( 1.0, 0.0);
    vec2 c10 = vertTexCoord.st + vec2( 0.0,-1.0);
    vec2 c12 = vertTexCoord.st + vec2( 0.0, 1.0);
    vec2 c00 = vertTexCoord.st + vec2(-1.0,-1.0);
    vec2 c02 = vertTexCoord.st + vec2(-1.0, 1.0);
    vec2 c20 = vertTexCoord.st + vec2( 1.0,-1.0);
    vec2 c22 = vertTexCoord.st + vec2( 1.0, 1.0);

    vec3 x11 = texture2D(source, c11).rgb;
    vec3 x01 = texture2D(source, c01).rgb;
    vec3 x21 = texture2D(source, c21).rgb;
    vec3 x10 = texture2D(source, c10).rgb;
    vec3 x12 = texture2D(source, c12).rgb;
    vec3 x00 = texture2D(source, c00).rgb;
    vec3 x02 = texture2D(source, c02).rgb;
    vec3 x20 = texture2D(source, c20).rgb;
    vec3 x22 = texture2D(source, c22).rgb;

    vec3 d01 = F(x11,x01,1.0);  
    vec3 d21 = F(x11,x21,1.0);  
    vec3 d10 = F(x11,x10,1.0);  
    vec3 d12 = F(x11,x12,1.0);  
    vec3 d00 = F(x11,x00,diag); 
    vec3 d02 = F(x11,x02,diag); 
    vec3 d20 = F(x11,x20,diag); 
    vec3 d22 = F(x11,x22,diag); 

    vec3 result = (x11 + d01+d21+d10+d12 + d00+d02+d20+d22);

    vec3 col = texture2D(source, ix).rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(col*result,1.0);
}
```

Comment: What kind of effect are you trying to accomplish?  From the above code, I assume that `T` is a floating point variable.  It appears as though it is never given a value.  I assume that means it is either initialized to zero or treated as a null pointer - thus perhaps you have a divide by zero or some other error originating in the `F()` function.  I don't know how glsl works under the hood.

Comment: Oh, never mind.  My apology, I just looked up the definition of `uniform`.

Comment: No worries, my client program (Processing) is sending a float for T, which seems to have no problem.

Comment: I'm looking for obvious mistakes in the code, computations generally I can suss out. Forgive my ignorance of glsl, but what does it mean, in the first snippet `shader(shader)`?  I would assume in that case that the shader would need data such as an image.  It seems that code is passing a reference to the shader to itself.

Comment: That is to some degree a confusion of mine as well, but checking other shaders in Processing, it doesn't seem to be an issue. shader() appears to just be fed whatever data appears within the draw() function, unless it's reset/flushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1) In `inkspread.glsl`, you've defined `uniform sampler2D source`, however you've never set this uniform on your shader. If you want to pass a PImage or PGraphics object into a shader via this uniform, you'd have to call `shader.set("source", photo)` in the same way you're passing in `T` for time. HOWEVER, Processing already gives you a texture for free. If you change `source` to `texture` throughout your shader file, Processing will automagically pass the main drawing canvas into your shader's `uniform sampler2D texture`. Your varying `vertTexCoord` is another special property that Processing automatically hands your fragment shader. There are a few more of those, but I don't think they're currently well-documented.

2) The second issue is the order of your image() & shader() calls. Since your shader is intended to post-process an image, you'll want to draw your image first, then call the shader to act on the main drawing canvas. Then everything should work properly. It should look like this:

```
void draw() {
    image(photo,619,619);
    shader.set("T",(float) millis()/1000.0);
    shader(shader);
}
```

I've tested this fix, and everything works. I'm not sure what the intended effect is, but your shader gave my photo a nice darken/saturation effect.

Comment: Thank you! I still have some work to go on the shader itself, but this has helped getting it actually running.

Answer (score 0):

> The color stays black, and when I change gl_FragColor = vertColor; (which Processing reserves for colro), the image becomes white.

I assume that vertColor is the position of the vertex interpreted as color. In that case, everything above 1 is clamped to 1, so if you have the vertex position at (1,1,1) the color is white. If you vertex position is at (2,2,2), it will be clamped to (1,1,1) and therefore the color is white again. 
You would have a non-white color where at least one of the position values is <1.
For testing purposes you could try to scale your vertColor here from 0 ( formerly the lowest of the position coordinates) to 1 (formerly the highest of your position coordiantes)

I cant answer on your original question, as you do a lot of float calculations but there is no way to determine, what would be set as gl_FragColor

Comment: I was helped through the float calculations, and I can only assume that those represent just one color channel (so I should just change it to a vec3 or something). The scaling of vertColor seems odd to me, just because in general vertColor seems to be treated as if it's 0 - 1 in the other Processing shaders I've seen.

Comment: I've made an update, using sampler2D(source,coord).rgb instead of vertColor, which continues to have the same problem.

Comment: try using `verTexCoord.st` instead of your calculated `c` values for you reading of the `x` values. in an ideal case they have no visible effect anyway, but right now they could make problems, i'm not sure about default settings of glsl.
also try not using result in gl_FragColor, just to see if the result is not a black screen.